# Extract text from a string using Powershell

Tags: string, powershell

I have a URL from which I need to extract a text. The URL is of the form:

```
abcd.com/File1/00012121
abcd.com/File12/00012121
abcd.com/File123/00012121
```

I need to extract File1, File12 and File123 respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
('abcd.com/File1/00012121' -split '/')[1]
```

Or:

```
'bcd.com/File1/00012121' -split '/' | Select -First 1 -Skip 1
```

Comment: You can use `-Index 1` instead of `-First 1 -Skip 1`.

Comment: Awesome tip PetSerAl! Didn't know this, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$URL -replace '.+\/(\w+)' , '$1'
```